# Pip install from local repo AND pypi.org

Tags: pip, pypi

I wanted to be able to pip install from multiple local repositories as well as pypi.org for public packages I wasn't hosting.

I could not manage to get my pip.ini configuration to work correctly, but when I removed the pip.ini from the various loading directories (global,user,site) I was able to pip install from pypi.org.

This made me believe that my pypi.org url must be the issue.

**My question is: does anyone have an example pip.ini file for accessing local repos and public repos?**

I successfully identified my problem.

I was using the url: "https://pypi.org"
I then changed it to: "https://pypi.org/simple"

Then my pip install commands worked.

Example pip.ini

```
[global]
retries=0
index-url = http://<mylocal1>.net:<PORT>
extra-index-url = http://<mylocal2>.net:<PORT> https://pypi.org/simple

trusted-host=<mylocal1>.net <mylocal2>.net
```

Hopes this helps someone else!

Comment: You should split your answer into an actual answer, and mark it as accepted yourself.